# Error al convertir el tipo de datos nvarchar a smalldatetime

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

estoy haciendo pruebas de inserción, tengo un problema al tratar de hacer un insert a mi sp, mi fecha es de tipo smalldatetime, pero a la hora de hacer la inserción me marca error Error al convertir el tipo de datos nvarchar a smalldatetime "Error al convertir el tipo de datos nvarchar a smalldatetime", estoy usando Entity Framework para trabajar con el sp y uso DBContext, adjunto una parte de mi código

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter Fecha = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@fecha", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime);

Fecha.Value = DateTime.Now;

var res = await _applicationDbContext.defaultResponse.FromSqlRaw("EXEC spSetFecha @fecha", Fecha).ToListAsync();
```

Adjunto como se ve cuando se ejecuta mi Sp

```
EXEC dbo.spSetFecha @fecha= null, -- smalldatetime
```

Adjunto el sp

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spSetFecha
(
    @fecha SMALLDATETIME = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.FechaPrueba(Fecha)
        VALUES (@fecha)
END
GO
```

Comment: Si ejecuto el Sp no tengo problemas ya que ingreso por ejemplo '20240214 00:00:00' y si lo inserta, pero ahora que quiero hacerlo desde codigo no puedo

Comment: es un string pero cuando ejecuto el sp desde el sql server agregando asi la fecha si me inserta a la tabla, pero en código mando DateTime.Now y marca ese error

Comment: lo intente pero aun me marcaba ese error

Comment: Antes que esto se convierta en chat, voy a eliminar mis comentarios dejando solo este: Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que tienes en ese Store Procedure.

Comment: muchas gracias..

Comment: Te sugiero que en vez de pasar la fecha como  un variable tipo DataTime, la conviertas en un string con el formato correcto  'fecha.ToString("YYYYMMDD")',  ya que cuando se genera el script se crear con la fecha en otro formato que no acepta smalldatetime

Comment: no habria problema con el casteo? ya que sino me equivoco marcaría error por enviar un string

Comment: edita la pregunta y agrega lo que tienes dentro de ese SP `spSetFecha`, aquí unas recomendaciones generales sobre cómo elaborar preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos. PD: también elimina los primeros comentarios de tu parte.

Comment: muchas gracias, agregué el sp

Comment: Hola @TrasharTheDragon podrías decir si la respuesta dada te resultó útil, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Los tipos de datos **SmallDateTime** almacenan la fecha y la hora juntas, pero solo almacenan la hora hasta el minuto, no almacena los segundos.

**SmallDateTime** no es compatible con **ANSI** o **ISO 8601**. Microsoft recomienda no usar los tipos de datos **DateTime** y **SmallDateTime**. En su lugar, puedes utilizar tipos  de datos **date** o  **datetime2** ya que son compatibles con el **estándar SQL**, son portátiles y tienen mejor alcance y precisión.

Por tanto la declaración de tu variable debería quedar como:

```
@fecha date = NULL;
```

**Referencia**: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16